# android window death and application crash

Tags: android

I got a message as below:

```
ERROR/ActivityManager(80): fail to set top app changed!
```

then application crashed, ActivityManager force finishing all pages. The screen black, then the home page re_load slowly.

**My phone : htc g8 wildfire  os2.1**

It maybe related with google map. Because I use GoogleMap in my application. This Question occur when the user use the googleMap frequently.( Bad influence for user)

Anybody has ideas? Please help me, thanks.

Not any exception message exists in LogCat.

---

**LogCat Logs:**

```
11-23 15:39:48.916: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=android.app.AlertDialog focus=true
11-23 15:39:49.776: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity focus=true
11-23 15:39:51.166: ERROR/libagl(87): uses alphaPlaneWorkaround
11-23 15:39:51.526: DEBUG/LocationMasfClient(87): getNetworkLocation(): Returning cache location with accuracy 75.0
11-23 15:39:52.076: DEBUG/LocationManagerService(87): Acquired wakelock
11-23 15:39:52.116: DEBUG/LocationManagerService(87): Released wakelock
11-23 15:39:53.076: DEBUG/dalvikvm(547): GC freed 7842 objects / 523016 bytes in 273ms
11-23 15:39:53.457: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
11-23 15:39:53.466: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity }
11-23 15:39:53.516: DEBUG/Sensors(87): open_akm, fd=153
11-23 15:39:53.536: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass Start
11-23 15:39:53.566: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
11-23 15:39:53.576: DEBUG/Sensors(87): close_akm, fd=153
11-23 15:39:53.606: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity focus=false
11-23 15:39:53.676: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity focus=true
11-23 15:39:53.916: DEBUG/FriendStreamWidgetView(856): onLayoutRemovedOrActivityDestroy
11-23 15:39:53.916: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Displayed activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity: 416 ms (total 416 ms)
11-23 15:39:54.016: DEBUG/dalvikvm(856): threadid=21 wakeup: interrupted
11-23 15:39:54.046: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass CLOSE 
11-23 15:39:54.057: INFO/Process(856): Sending signal. PID: 856 SIG: 9
11-23 15:39:54.076: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44dc6098 com.htc.launcher/com.htc.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
11-23 15:39:54.086: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Process com.htc.launcher (pid 856) has died.
11-23 15:39:54.116: DEBUG/NewsService(934): onDestroy
11-23 15:39:54.116: DEBUG/StockScheduler(206): exit()
11-23 15:39:54.136: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): MediaPlayback is onUnbind: null ref count: 0
11-23 15:39:54.136: ERROR/MediaPlaybackService(532): BadQueue mPlayListLen : 0 mAlbumListLen : 0 mShrinkAlbumListLen : 0
11-23 15:39:54.146: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): saveQueue mPlayListLen : 0
11-23 15:39:54.146: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): saveQueue mAlbumListLen : 0
11-23 15:39:54.146: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): saveQueue mShrinkAlbumListLen : 0
11-23 15:39:54.176: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): onUnbind finished
11-23 15:39:54.186: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): !!!! @@@@@@@@ onDestroy
11-23 15:39:54.196: DEBUG/JOGBALL(87): Jogball, + set_jogball_mode mode=0
11-23 15:39:54.196: VERBOSE/HtcLockScreen(87): get INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION_REMOVE, stop music
11-23 15:39:54.206: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(532): unregisterHDMINotification
11-23 15:39:54.216: ERROR/MusicPluginManager(532): resetMusicPluginManager called!!
11-23 15:39:54.216: DEBUG/MediaPlaybackService(532): onDestroy finished
11-23 15:39:55.296: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
11-23 15:39:55.296: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity }
11-23 15:39:55.326: DEBUG/Sensors(87): open_akm, fd=149
11-23 15:39:55.336: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass Start
11-23 15:39:55.356: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
11-23 15:39:55.387: DEBUG/Sensors(87): close_akm, fd=149
11-23 15:39:55.426: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity focus=false
11-23 15:39:55.546: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity focus=true
11-23 15:39:55.706: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Displayed activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity: 396 ms (total 396 ms)
11-23 15:39:55.906: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): setMinTime: 2000
11-23 15:39:55.916: DEBUG/WifiService(87): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@447f3bd8}
11-23 15:39:55.916: DEBUG/WifiService(87): enable and start wifi due to updateWifiState
11-23 15:39:55.967: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass CLOSE 
11-23 15:39:57.596: DEBUG/WifiService(87): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@447f3bd8}
11-23 15:39:57.596: DEBUG/WifiService(87): enable and start wifi due to updateWifiState
11-23 15:39:57.606: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): getLocation(): triggering a wifi scan
11-23 15:39:57.606: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(190): wpa_supplicant_ctrl_iface_ap_scan: 2
11-23 15:39:57.606: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(190): Scan request
11-23 15:39:57.656: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): onCellLocationChanged [21124,18941]
11-23 15:39:57.796: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=android.app.AlertDialog focus=true
11-23 15:39:57.896: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity focus=false
11-23 15:39:58.576: INFO/wpa_supplicant(190): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
11-23 15:39:58.586: INFO/wpa_supplicant(190): - wpa_supplicant_event_scan_results RETURN (ap_scan = 2)-
11-23 15:39:58.586: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(190): wpa_supplicant_ctrl_iface_ap_scan: 1
11-23 15:39:58.626: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): updateWifIScanResults(): 9 APs
11-23 15:39:58.656: DEBUG/LocationMasfClient(87): getNetworkLocation(): Returning cache location with accuracy 75.0
11-23 15:39:58.826: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity focus=true
11-23 15:39:58.876: WARN/InputManagerService(87): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4482ab90
11-23 15:39:58.936: DEBUG/LocationManagerService(87): Acquired wakelock
11-23 15:39:58.957: DEBUG/LocationManagerService(87): Released wakelock
11-23 15:39:59.216: DEBUG/dalvikvm(547): GC freed 7514 objects / 523712 bytes in 102ms
11-23 15:39:59.547: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
11-23 15:39:59.556: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity }
11-23 15:39:59.576: DEBUG/Sensors(87): open_akm, fd=148
11-23 15:39:59.596: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass Start
11-23 15:39:59.606: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
11-23 15:39:59.637: DEBUG/Sensors(87): close_akm, fd=148
11-23 15:39:59.666: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity focus=false
11-23 15:39:59.756: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(1295): DebugMonitor class=com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity focus=true
11-23 15:40:00.026: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Displayed activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity: 461 ms (total 461 ms)
11-23 15:40:00.046: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87): Uninstalling process com.ceosoft.alumlife
11-23 15:40:00.046: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87): Force removing process ProcessRecord{44985ae0 1295:com.ceosoft.alumlife/10056} (com.ceosoft.alumlife/10056)
11-23 15:40:00.066: INFO/Process(87): Sending signal. PID: 1295 SIG: 9
11-23 15:40:00.077: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity
11-23 15:40:00.077: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44c64238 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.086: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.086: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44929e30 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.086: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity
11-23 15:40:00.096: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass CLOSE 
11-23 15:40:00.096: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44efd9f8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.096: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity
11-23 15:40:00.107: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44e60180 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.107: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.107: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44ddbe20 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.116: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity
11-23 15:40:00.116: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{448c7380 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.127: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): settings
11-23 15:40:00.136: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.checkin
11-23 15:40:00.136: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c230b0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.136: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44b81008 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.WelcomePhotoActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.136: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c93400 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.LoginActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.146: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44dc52a0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.146: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44ae2800 Loading paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.146: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44bd5c08 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.MainActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.156: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44eaa0d0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.156: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44d1c2d0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.156: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44baa668 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.MainActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.166: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c79b50 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.166: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44cb0268 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.166: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c4eec0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.176: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{448db420 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.186: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.settings
11-23 15:40:00.197: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44db2478 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.197: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44ecdc68 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.197: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{448bc038 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.206: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44ce0d40 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.206: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44b990d8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.206: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44ed0fd0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.216: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44ed1630 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.216: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44d09548 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.216: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c03570 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.227: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44cf6370 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLocationActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.227: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44d405f0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.236: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44caf158 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.236: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.246: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.vpn
11-23 15:40:00.256: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{448c6f38 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.256: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{448cb150 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.266: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c537c8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity paused=true}
11-23 15:40:00.266: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44c2ef18 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.266: INFO/WindowManager(87): WIN DEATH: Window{44d907e8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/com.ceosoft.alumlife.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity paused=false}
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44c97590 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44cd2cd0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44ecc5d0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44d085b8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44db60e8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderByLastNameActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44decc00 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.286: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity
11-23 15:40:00.286: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44e53b08 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.296: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.wdm
11-23 15:40:00.296: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.settings.accountsync
11-23 15:40:00.306: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.android.htcsetupwizard
11-23 15:40:00.306: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.broadcom.bt.app.system
11-23 15:40:00.306: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity
11-23 15:40:00.316: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): android
11-23 15:40:00.316: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44d4ce40 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultMapViewActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.316: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity
11-23 15:40:00.326: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44b0d9a8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderResultActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.326: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.326: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity
11-23 15:40:00.326: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): location
11-23 15:40:00.336: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.htcCheckin
11-23 15:40:00.336: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{448e68e8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.finder.AlumniFinderActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.336: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.MainActivity
11-23 15:40:00.336: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44d7c800 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.MainActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.346: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.MainActivity
11-23 15:40:00.346: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.AddProgramWidget
11-23 15:40:00.346: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44c5f7e8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.MainActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.356: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): CSDFunctionG
11-23 15:40:00.356: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.WelcomePhotoActivity
11-23 15:40:00.356: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44f2ae88 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.WelcomePhotoActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.356: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.LoginActivity
11-23 15:40:00.366: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.386: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): setMinTime: 2000
11-23 15:40:00.396: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): settings
11-23 15:40:00.396: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.checkin
11-23 15:40:00.407: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.settings
11-23 15:40:00.417: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.vpn
11-23 15:40:00.426: DEBUG/Sensors(87): open_akm, fd=122
11-23 15:40:00.436: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Start proc com.ceosoft.alumlife for activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.EntryActivity: pid=1413 uid=10056 gids={3003, 1015}
11-23 15:40:00.436: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87):   Force finishing activity com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.EntryActivity
11-23 15:40:00.446: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.wdm
11-23 15:40:00.457: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass Start
11-23 15:40:00.486: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.settings.accountsync
11-23 15:40:00.496: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.android.htcsetupwizard
11-23 15:40:00.506: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.broadcom.bt.app.system
11-23 15:40:00.516: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): android
11-23 15:40:00.527: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.527: INFO/ActivityManager(87): Start proc com.htc.launcher for activity com.htc.launcher/.Launcher: pid=1418 uid=9999 gids={3003, 1015, 3002, 3001}
11-23 15:40:00.536: ERROR/ActivityManager(87): fail to set top app changed!
11-23 15:40:00.546: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1418): Rosie launcher will have a 32MB heap
11-23 15:40:00.546: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): location
11-23 15:40:00.576: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.htcCheckin
11-23 15:40:00.576: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.AddProgramWidget
11-23 15:40:00.586: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): CSDFunctionG
11-23 15:40:00.586: DEBUG/ActivityManager(87): Received spurious death notification for thread android.os.BinderProxy@44edaa70
11-23 15:40:00.586: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{44bd9ea0 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.LoginActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.596: WARN/ActivityManager(87): Activity HistoryRecord{448b9da8 com.ceosoft.alumlife/.activity.EntryActivity} being finished, but not in LRU list
11-23 15:40:00.626: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.636: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): setMinTime: 2000
11-23 15:40:00.636: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): settings
11-23 15:40:00.647: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.checkin
11-23 15:40:00.666: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.settings
11-23 15:40:00.666: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): server.vpn
11-23 15:40:00.666: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.wdm
11-23 15:40:00.686: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.settings.accountsync
11-23 15:40:00.716: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.android.htcsetupwizard
11-23 15:40:00.716: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.broadcom.bt.app.system
11-23 15:40:00.716: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): android
11-23 15:40:00.736: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.746: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): location
11-23 15:40:00.776: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.htcCheckin
11-23 15:40:00.776: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): com.htc.AddProgramWidget
11-23 15:40:00.786: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): CSDFunctionG
11-23 15:40:00.816: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): removeListener(): providers.subscribedfeeds
11-23 15:40:00.816: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): setMinTime: 540000
11-23 15:40:00.986: INFO/dalvikvm(1413): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=38)
11-23 15:40:01.056: INFO/dalvikvm(1418): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=38)
11-23 15:40:01.076: INFO/dalvikvm(1413): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=44)
11-23 15:40:01.097: DEBUG/Sensors(87): close_akm, fd=122
11-23 15:40:01.136: INFO/UsageStats(87): Unexpected resume of com.htc.launcher while already resumed in com.ceosoft.alumlife
11-23 15:40:01.146: WARN/dalvikvm(87): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
11-23 15:40:01.157: INFO/dalvikvm(1418): Debugger thread not active, ignoring DDM send (t=0x41504e4d l=36)
11-23 15:40:01.196: WARN/dalvikvm(1418): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar'
11-23 15:40:01.266: INFO/ActivityThread(1418): Publishing provider com.htc.launcher.settings: com.htc.launcher.LauncherProvider
11-23 15:40:01.496: DEBUG/AK8973(67): Compass CLOSE 
11-23 15:40:01.516: WARN/SettingUtil(1418): loadSettings(), cursor == null, content provider is not exist
11-23 15:40:01.886: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1418): GC freed 2766 objects / 235752 bytes in 103ms
11-23 15:40:02.586: DEBUG/WifiService(87): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@447f3bd8}
11-23 15:40:02.586: DEBUG/WifiService(87): enable and start wifi due to updateWifiState
11-23 15:40:02.666: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1418): GC freed 1319 objects / 97424 bytes in 163ms
11-23 15:40:02.866: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): setMinTime: 540000
11-23 15:40:02.897: DEBUG/WifiService(87): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationProvider type=2 binder=android.os.Binder@447f3bd8}
11-23 15:40:02.916: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(87): onCellLocationChanged [21124,18941]
11-23 15:40:02.936: DEBUG/WifiService(87): enable and start wifi due to updateWifiState
11-23 15:40:03.096: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(1418): load applications
11-23 15:40:03.116: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(1418): loading user items
11-23 15:40:03.116: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(1418):   --> starting workspace loader
11-23 15:40:03.116: DEBUG/RosieDbDebug(1418): startLoaders(false)
11-23 15:40:03.146: INFO/HtcLockScreen(87): get INTENT_ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED
11-23 15:40:03.386: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1418): GetFieldID: unable to find field Ljava/util/Hashtable;.loadFactor:F
```

Comment: Please post the complete log....

Comment: have you got your map apikey?

Comment: Yes, I have a map apikey. I'm sure it is able to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Amith GC 、 sugarynugs 's response

This is my  mistakes ：

I put the code (as follows) at a Previous activity's **onPause() method**.

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

am.restartPackage(getPackageName());

System.exit(0);
```

---

That's why the application exit normally  and window death!

This's my mistake